# Cordova - how to save an image to iOS photo gallery?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

We are using the Cordova file plugin to save images to device image **gallery**. Works fine on Android but can't save an image to the iOS photo gallery using [this tutorial](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/150/how-to-create-an-image-file-from-a-base64-string-on-the-device-with-cordova). We have used the following paths but no luck so far.

```
folderpath = window.cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + "Library/";
folderpath = window.cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
folderpath = window.cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory;
folderpath = window.cordova.file.dataDirectory;
```

please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-save-image

You should use this plugin

```
window.cordova.plugins.imagesaver.saveImageToGallery(nativePathToJpegImage, function(success){}, function(error){});
```

nativePathToJpegImage is folderpath.